# special characters in ssh2

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, ssh

i am writing a linux terminal in nodejs,
using the ssh2 package shell().
it works for me with regular commands,
but when editing files with vi editor,
and then escaping the editor, i need to simulate a "escape" key
press. i tried this:

```
stream.write("^[")
```

after reading http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html
but it did not work.
so my question is - how can i simulate special characters (ctrl, shift...) press in ssh2?

or is there any other higher api node package that i can use
to create a terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The escape character is sometimes displayed as `^[`, but that is not how you write it in a javascript string. Try `"\x1B"` or `"\033"` if you prefer octal.